# How to replace a background image of a div, while choosing the matching responsive image file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have a website with a responsive background image for a `div`.

I choose which size of the image to take through `@media` queries.

The div in question in the code has the id `banner-div`.

HTML:

```
<div id="header-div">
    <div id="background-clipped-div">
        <div id="banner-div">
            <div id="scroll-down-div" onclick="scrollToMainContent()">
                <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #banner-div {
        background-image: url(images/background-1-small.png);
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #banner-div {
        background-image: url(images/background-1-medium.png);
    }
}

@media only screen {
    #banner-div {
        background-image: url(images/background-1-big.png);
    }
}
```

#### Question:

If I now want to swap/replace the image, for example by having an ever changing background image between multiple different images, how would I do that while respecting the correct image for a given resolution?

Let us say I have the following images in the `images` folder:

- background-1-small.png
- background-1-medium.png
- background-1-big.png
- background-2-small.png
- background-2-medium.png
- background-2-big.png

*I know how to replace the path to the current image in JavaScript, but I 
did not find a way to replace all `@media` queries.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matchMedia for that.
Here's how I would do it:
 - Each image container has it's responsive variations set as data-attributes so that we can access them in javascript for each breakpoint:

```js
var $elements = $(".element");
var mqls = [ // list of window.matchMedia() queries
    window.matchMedia("(min-width: 860px)"),
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)"),
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)")
]
 
for (var i=0; i<mqls.length; i++){ // loop through queries
    mediaqueryresponse(mqls[i]) // call handler function explicitly at run time
    mqls[i].addListener(mediaqueryresponse) // call handler function whenever the media query is triggered
}

function mediaqueryresponse(mql){
    // check which breakpoint we're in and send the parameter "big", "medium" or "small" to the setBakground function
    if (mqls[0].matches){
     setBackground("big")
    }
    if (mqls[1].matches){
     setBackground("medium")
    }
    if (mqls[2].matches){
     setBackground("small")
    }
}

function setBackground (size) {
  // Loop through each element that needs to have the responsive background images and change the background image based on the current breakpoint
  $elements.each(function() {
   $(this).css({
      "background-image": "url("+$(this).attr("data-"+size)+")"
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.element {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="element" data-big="//placehold.it/400x400?text=Big1" data-medium="//placehold.it/300x300?text=Medium1" data-small="//placehold.it/200x200?text=Small1"></div>

<div class="element" data-big="//placehold.it/402x402?text=Big2" data-medium="//placehold.it/302x302?text=Medium2" data-small="//placehold.it/202x202?text=Small2"></div>
```

EDIT: Sorry for the mix between vanilla js and jquery. I copied the first part from a website and then added the last parts with jquery.

EDIT2: Link to JS fiddle to test the responsiveness of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/q30u5o7j/

Comment: I do not understand it. What does `document.getElementById("match1")` find? Why write it in the HTML? And you never replace the image without changing the window size, which was the question. So your suggestion is to make the media query completely in JavaScript with `matchmedia(...)`, sounds good. So I could make a global variable which holds the current file url and switch that, the correct size could be calculated by your idea.

Comment: Since you used `mediaqueryresponse(mql)` two times, it was confusing. To change to another image I just call `setBackground(...)` function every few seconds with a new index. So now it will be called in the carousel and when the document size changes. Thanks for the hint to `matchMedia(...)`.

Comment: sorry for the getElementById, it was a leftover from another script. In theory there's no need to call a function every few seconds, the "mqls[i].addListener(mediaqueryresponse)" part means that the mediaqueryresponse function will be called every time a new breakpoint is evaluated. In there I check what breakpoint it is and call a function to set the backgrounds. In that function you can loop through all your elements and set the background accordingly. I updated my snipped to show how it would work with multiple elements and added a link to jsfiddle to test it's responsiveness.

Comment: PS: sorry for the confusion